# Graphql subscription does not catch client-side variables

Tags: filter, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to use graphql subscriptions using the following libraries:

[graphql-subscription](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-subscriptions) on the server-side

[subscription-transport-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subscriptions-transport-ws) on the client-side

and when not using the filtering mechanism every thing goes right. But when I add the `withFilter` function into it, encounter the issue that no variable or context object receives to the filtering function.

For example I want to filter data according to the group. The client requests the server with the following query:

[image: request body]

And at the server-side the implemented method is like this:

```
        this.resolvers.Subscription[subscription.name] = {
            subscribe: withFilter((...params) => {console.log('subscription params: ', ...params); return this.pubsub.asyncIterator(subscription.name.toUpperCase());}, (...params) => {
                console.log('filtering params: ', ...params)
                return true // payload[subscription.name]._group === variables._group;
            }),
        };
```

which is creating some subscriptions dynamically (and its dynamicity does not relate to this issue). Now the two logs that I have made above will be as following:

> subscription params: `null {} null null`
>
> filtering params: `{
>         message_onMessage: {
>           text: 'test',
>           _offline_id: '1587981902663',
>           _status: 3,
>           time: 1587981902713,
>           _id: 1587981902716,
>           _rev: 1587981902716
>         }
>       } {} null null`

So that in the callback that is passed to the `withFilter` function which is used to filter the data, I do not have the variables object and the context object to fetch the requester `_group` parameter.

And the installed version of the libraries is as bellow:

```
// server
"graphql": "^14.6.0",
"graphql-subscriptions": "^1.1.0",
// client
"graphql": "^15.0.0",
"graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16"
```

Comment: I do not understand your comment @xadm. Either if it is a question or what. But in this case `...params` is used to catch all the parameters as a debug technique.

Comment: try "normal" `(value, args, context, info)` args definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gave up to use variables as I figured out that I can send parameters like query and mutation requests. So I have changed the request so that it now makes queries like this:

[image: new query parameters]

And also server accepts that parameter in the type definition of the subscriptions. Now the input parameters of the `withFilter` filter function (the second callback) are payload and variables which are respectively, data published by a mutation and data retrieved from the subscriber.

So now with the above request, current function works perfect:

```
        this.resolvers.Subscription[subscription.name] = {
            subscribe: withFilter(_ => this.pubsub.asyncIterator(subscription.name.toUpperCase()), (payload, variables) => {
                console.log(payload, variables);
                return payload[subscription.name]._group === variables._group;
            }),
        };
```

Although I didn't figure out how to make use of variables sent in request, my problem got solved.

Comment: ... but it doesn't cover eventual security checks (owner compared with logged user - context) ?